# Varnish: Saving product clears all product pages

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish

When I programmatically update a product, all cached products (varnish) seem to be cleared. This is the header from the purge request:

```
ReqHeader      X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: ((^|,)cat_p_3478(,|$))|((^|,)cat_p(,|$))
```

I think it's the **cat_p** tag that causes the clearing, but I don't understand why all pages tagged with this tag need to be cleared.
This simple code triggers the purge request:

```
$product = $productRepository->get($data->sku);
$product->setStoreId(0);
$product->save();
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution, I had the areacode set to 'frontend'. So I changed

```
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
```

to

```
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('webapi_rest');
```

This removes the **cat_p** tag from the purge request.